# replace a word (its appears twice) i need replace the last. sql

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2005, replace

they are my rows

```
Número Total de Clientes
Número Total de Clientes de
Número Total de Líquidos que se Consumen en el Hogar a la Semana
Número Total de Líquidos que se Consumen en el Hogar a la Semana de
Número Total de garrafones de
Número Total de garrafones en el mercado
Númeto Total de garrafones de
Porcentaje Clientes que Compran por Calidad
Porcentaje Clientes que Compran por Disponibilidad
Porcentaje Clientesque Compran por Otros Motivos
Porcentaje Clientesque Compran por Precio
Porcentaje Total de garrafones de
Porcentaje de Clientes
Porcentaje de Clientes xxxx que Compran en la Ruta Hogar
Porcentaje de Clientes de
Porcentaje de Participación de Ventas de
Porcentaje de garrafones de
```

my table is named #ope_censo_indicador

you could see  i have those

```
Número Total de Clientes
Número Total de Clientes de
```

i need it was
    Número Total de Clientes marca

but i got
    Número Total de Clientes
    Número Total marcaClientes marca

with this query

```
update #ope_censo_indicador set ope_indicadoridname=(replace(ope_indicadoridname,'%de','%marca'))
where ope_indicadoridname like '% de'
```

with these too

```
 Número Total de Líquidos que se Consumen en el Hogar a la Semana
 Número Total de Líquidos que se Consumen en el Hogar a la Semana de
```

i need it return

```
 Número Total de Líquidos que se Consumen en el Hogar a la Semana
 Número Total de Líquidos que se Consumen en el Hogar a la Semana marca
```

this too

```
Porcentaje de Clientes Porcentaje de Clientes Cristal que Compran en
la Ruta Hogar Porcentaje de Clientes de
```

i need return

```
 Porcentaje de Clientes Porcentaje de Clientes Cristal que Compran en
 la Ruta Hogar Porcentaje de Clientes marca
```

( i have more but it would great i got it with one query)

after it, i'll have.

```
Número Total de Clientes
Número Total de Clientes marca
Número Total de Líquidos que se Consumen en el Hogar a la Semana
Número Total de Líquidos que se Consumen en el Hogar a la Semana marca
Número Total de garrafones marca
Número Total de garrafones en el mercado
Porcentaje Clientes que Compran por Calidad
Porcentaje Clientes que Compran por Disponibilidad
Porcentaje Clientesque Compran por Otros Motivos
Porcentaje Clientesque Compran por Precio
Porcentaje Total de garrafones marca
Porcentaje de Clientes
Porcentaje de Clientes xxxx que Compran en la Ruta Hogar
Porcentaje de Clientes marca
Porcentaje de Participación de Ventas marca
Porcentaje de garrafones marca
```

i am going to want to delete those (or to do a query with a distinct but i'll need return this:)

```
Número Total de Clientes marca
Número Total de Líquidos que se Consumen en el Hogar a la Semana marca
Número Total de garrafones marca
Número Total de garrafones en el mercado
Porcentaje Clientes que Compran por Calidad
Porcentaje Clientes que Compran por Disponibilidad
Porcentaje Clientesque Compran por Otros Motivos
Porcentaje Clientesque Compran por Precio
Porcentaje Total de garrafones marca
Porcentaje de Clientes xxxx que Compran en la Ruta Hogar
Porcentaje de Clientes marca
Porcentaje de Participación de Ventas marca
Porcentaje de garrafones marca



enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was tricky!  I am assuming you are basically saying you want to replace the LAST "de" with "marca" but only if it is the LAST word.  If it is in the middle you want to leave it alone.

If that is correct, this code handles it:

```
-- Setup a temp table with "bigstring" as your text and "lastpos" as the location of LAST "de"
 DECLARE @tmp1 TABLE (bigstring varchar(1000), lastpos int)
 INSERT INTO @tmp1 (bigstring) VALUES ('Número Total de Líquidos que se Consumen en el Hogar a la Semana')
 INSERT INTO @tmp1 (bigstring) VALUES ('Número Total de Líquidos que se Consumen en el Hogar a la Semana de')
 INSERT INTO @tmp1 (bigstring) VALUES ('Leave this de one alone')

  -- Ensure we don't have any trailing spaces
  UPDATE @tmp1 SET bigstring = RTRIM(bigstring)

  -- If the string ENDS in ' de' then record the starting position of that word
  UPDATE @tmp1 SET lastpos = LEN(bigstring)-2 WHERE RIGHT(bigstring,3) = ' de'

  -- Here is how our table looks now
  SELECT * from @tmp1

  -- Now, if LASTPOS is not null, we want everything to the LEFT of that + 'marca'
  UPDATE @tmp1 SET bigstring = SUBSTRING(bigstring, 1, lastpos) + 'marca' WHERE lastpos IS NOT NULL

  -- Done!
  SELECT * from @tmp1
```

Your first string was left alone, the second has the final "de" replaced with "marca" and the one I put in there (with "de" in the middle) was left alone.

I hope that helps!